# Thread-safety while reading bool property without locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, thread-safety, volatile

I've been trying to track down an extremely weird issue that occurs *very rarely* and takes a long time to manifest. This code pattern seemed to stand out, and I wanted to ensure this is thread-safe. A simplified form of the pattern here shows a `TestClassManager` class that manages leasing for `TestClass` objects. A `TestClass` object will get leased, used, and released. Once a `TestClass` is released, it will *not* be modified/used by any other thread further.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var testClassManager = new TestClassManager();

        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestersOperationLoop(testClassManager), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ClearTestersLoop(testClassManager), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    public class TestClassManager
    {
        private readonly object _testerCollectionLock = new object();

        private readonly Dictionary<long, TestClass> _leasedTesters = new Dictionary<long, TestClass>();
        private readonly Dictionary<long, TestClass> _releasedTesters = new Dictionary<long, TestClass>();

        public TestClass LeaseTester()
        {
            lock (_testerCollectionLock)
            {
                var tester = new TestClass();

                _leasedTesters.Add(tester.Id, tester);
                _releasedTesters.Remove(tester.Id);

                return tester;
            }
        }

        public void ReleaseTester(long id)
        {
            lock (_testerCollectionLock)
            {
                var tester = _leasedTesters[id];

                _leasedTesters.Remove(tester.Id);
                _releasedTesters.Add(tester.Id, tester);
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            lock (_testerCollectionLock)
            {
                foreach (var tester in _releasedTesters)
                {
                    if (!tester.Value.IsChanged)
                    {
                        // I have not seen this exception throw ever, but can this happen?
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Is this even possible!?!");
                    }
                }

                var clearCount = _releasedTesters.Count;

                _releasedTesters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        private static long _count;

        private long _id;
        private bool _status;

        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

        public TestClass()
        {
            Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        }

        // reading status without the lock
        public bool IsChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }
        }

        public long Id { get => _id; set => _id = value; }

        public void SetStatusToTrue()
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                _status = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void TestersOperationLoop(TestClassManager testClassManager)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var tester = testClassManager.LeaseTester();

            tester.SetStatusToTrue();
            testClassManager.ReleaseTester(tester.Id);
        }
    }

    public static void ClearTestersLoop(TestClassManager testClassManager)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            testClassManager.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Is the check for `TestClass.IsChanged` property from within the `TestClassManager.Clear` method thread-safe? I don't ever see the `InvalidOperationException`, but is that possible? If it is, that would explain my issue.

Irrespective of that, I am going to lock the read anyway to follow commonly suggested pattern of *locked read if locked write*. But I wanted to get some closure on understanding if this would actually cause an issue, since this would explain that *extremely weird rare bug!!* that keeps me awake at night.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: Your code is thread-safe. You are correct in worrying that reads of the `_status` field through the `IsChanged` property may result in stale values; however, this won't happen in your `Clear` method, since the other existing `lock` statements already protect against this.

There are two related concepts that often get confused in multithreaded programming: [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and [memory consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model). Mutual exclusion involves the delineation of critical sections of your code, such that only one thread may execute them at any time. This is what [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) is primarily meant to achieve.

Memory consistency is a more esoteric topic, and deals with the order in which writes to memory locations by one thread may appear to reads of the same memory locations by other threads. Memory operations may appear to be reordered across threads for performance reasons, such as better utilization of local caches. Without synchronization, threads may read stale values of memory locations that have been updated by other threads – the write appears to have been performed *after* the read from the reader thread's perspective. To avoid such reordering, the programmer may introduce [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) into their code, which would prevent memory operations from being moved across. In practice, such memory barriers are usually only generated implicitly as the result of other threading operations. For example, the `lock` statement generates a memory barrier both on entry and on exit.

However, the generation of memory barriers by the `lock` statement is only a side-effect, since the primary purpose of `lock` is to enforce mutual exclusion. This can give rise to confusion when programmers encounter other situations where mutual exclusion is also achieved, but memory barriers are not implicitly generated. One such situation is the reading and writing of fields whose width is up to 32 or 64 bits, which are guaranteed to be atomic on architectures of that width. Reading or writing a boolean is inherently thread-safe – you never need a `lock` to enforce mutual exclusion while doing so, as no other concurrent thread may "corrupt" the value. However, reading or writing a boolean without a `lock` means that no memory barriers get generated, so stale values may result.

Let's apply this discussion to a stripped-down version of your code:

```
// Thread A:
_testerStatus = true;                  // tester.SetStatusToTrue();
_testerReleased = true;                // testClassManager.ReleaseTester(tester.Id);

// Thread B:
if (_testerReleased)                               // foreach (var tester in _releasedTesters)
    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {_testerStatus}"); //     if (!tester.Value.IsChanged)
```

Is it possible for the above program to ever output `false`? In this case, yes. This is the classic example discussed under [Nonblocking Synchronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) (recommended reading). The bug can be fixed by adding memory barriers (explicitly, as below, or implicitly, as discussed further below):

```
// Thread A:
_testerStatus = true;                  // tester.SetStatusToTrue();
Thread.MemoryBarrier();                // Barrier 1
_testerReleased = true;                // testClassManager.ReleaseTester(tester.Id);
Thread.MemoryBarrier();                // Barrier 2

// Thread B:
Thread.MemoryBarrier();                            // Barrier 3
if (_testerReleased)                               // foreach (var tester in _releasedTesters)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();                        //     Barrier 4
    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {_testerStatus}"); //     if (!tester.Value.IsChanged)
}
```

In your code, your `ReleaseTester` method has an outer `lock`, which implicitly generates the equivalent to Barriers 1 and 2 above. Similarly, your `Clear` method also has an outer `lock`, so it generates the equivalent to Barrier 3. Your code does not generate the equivalent to Barrier 4; however, I believe that this barrier is unnecessary in your case, since the mutual exclusion enforced by the `lock` entails that Barrier 2 *must* have been executed before Barrier 3 if the tester was released.

Comment: Only access to the collection is threadsafe, not access to the TestClass status.

Comment: @RodneyRichardson: Did you read the rest of my answer? Accessing a boolean is inherently "thread-safe" since it's an atomic type. Whether reads get a fresh value depends on the usage pattern. Under the code sample provided by the OP, they do.

Comment: @Douglas, I had a suspicion the outer lock must be preventing the stale reads. Your stripped down example puts things in a better perspective. I had some quick follow-up questions.
1. Would this be true with async primitives too?
2. Would the Barrier 4 still be _unnecessary_ if `_releasedTesters` cached some testers objects? Say, if couple of testers were existing in the collection even before the status was changed. The code sample may be confusing for this use-case, but imagine if it did not throw an InvalidOperationException, and just did some other processing instead.

Comment: @iambatman: 1. [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) says that the following (among others) implicitly generate full fences (memory barriers): "Asynchronous callbacks that use the thread pool — these include asynchronous delegates, APM callbacks, and Task continuations." The article was written before the async/await keywords were introduced, but await is similar to `Task.ContinueWith`, so it's likely the statement applies to it too.

Comment: 2. From this question, it seems like you're implementing the [object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), which involves flip-flopping `_status` continuously. In that case, it's unlikely that you can rely on the subsequent `lock`. If you're concerned about the performance hit of a `lock` on the field access, you can look into using one of the `Interlocked` or `Volatile` methods, or generating the memory barriers explicitly, but I would generally advise against this. An uncontended lock is surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is that in your `TestersOperationLoop` you `LeaseTester` which enables `ClearTestersLoop` from another thread to immediately `Clear` the newly leased test. Since at that point you haven't yet called `SetStatusToTrue`, the check in the `Clear` method will fail and the exception will be raised.

```cs
  var tester = testClassManager.LeaseTester();

  // Imagine that testClassManager.Clear(); gets called from the second thread at this point.
  //
  // Since _testerCollectionLock from testClassManager.LeaseTester() is already released, the Clear method from other thread can run as it can acquire the lock now.
  // This thread keeps running, and races to start executing the next line which would set the status to true and prevent the other thread from throwing exception.
  // But it is a nature of race conditions that there is a single winner... and in this case it is the other thread; checking for status which is not yet changed to true and thus throwing the exception :-(

  tester.SetStatusToTrue();
  testClassManager.ReLeaseTester(tester.Id);
```

The easiest fix in this case would be to set status of the TestClas inside LeaseTester method in the lock block.

```cs
public TestClass LeaseTester()
{
  lock (_testerCollectionLock)
  {
    var tester = new TestClass();

    tester.SetStatusToTrue();

    _leasedTesters.Add(tester.Id, tester);
    _releasedTesters.Remove(tester.Id);

    return tester;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! hmm...I might be missing something. The Clear mechanism should only iterate through the "released" testers. So, it should avoid testers that are still working on SetStatusToTrue operation. Unless I made a mistake in the sample, but at least in my real code the Clear operation would never be working on unreleased testers.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think I wrote too soon. I've put the code in VS and I really cannot see why the exception would be thrown. Can you confirm that you indeed can reproduce the exception with the code you provided? And that the exception is indeed an 'InvalidOperationException("Is this even possible!?!")'?

Comment: Sorry. I should've been clearer. I have not seen this exception so far in my test runs with this sample, but I was curious if this was a possibility? Because in the real system, the status may or may not change, and if a changed status is removed without processing, there will be no exception, but loss of critical information! This issue happens fairly infrequently, which makes me wonder if it might be something to do with a stale read of the IsChanged value since the read happens without a lock. I have added some comments in the sample for clarification.

Comment: I don't think the lock on read will help (and it is not even necessary to have it in setter). The way the code is written, there is no way that two threads can simultaneously read and write IsChanged property of the same object at the same time. If this is not whole code, there's a potential problem if some other thread calls ReleaseTester while TestersOperationLoop is between LeaseTester and SetStatusToTrue.

Comment: That was my assumption too! I had a remote suspicion that, _maybe_ IsChanged value sometimes ends up being stale since it is not locked. I am hesitant to use big words that I do not completely understand, but this suspicion was based on the fact that reads may not always be up to date all the time. [An example of non-volatile hazard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/january/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice-part-2#compiler-optimizations), but I am not sure if using another lock (_testerCollectionLock in this case) prevents that from happening.

Answer (score -1):

You are locking the collections of TestClass objects every time you add or remove, but there is no similar lock on the TestClass status itself. Hence, you are reading and modifying the same value on different threads outside of a lock.

It's difficult to recommend a fix without seeing what the actual usage is. Try looking at which values you're modifying and reading, and ensure they are only done within the same lock. One option is to make the TestManager's lock object publicly accessible, or add a shared lock object to all TestClass instances.

Comment: This answer provides good advice for novice programmers: always use a lock. However, the OP made it clear they're already familiar with this general recommendation, and are asking whether a lock-free implementation would work in their case. In that context, this answer is wrong, since code that is carefully synchronized with memory barriers does not need locks.